# How are ChildWindowFromPointEx and ChildWindowFromPoint different except the "flags" parameter?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Windows API has [`ChildWindowFromPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ChildWindowFromPointEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions and they differ in that the latter has *uFlags* parameter specifying which windows to skip.

It looks like if I pass `CWP_ALL` into `ChildWindowFromPointEx()` I'll get exactly the same effect as I would have with `ChildWindowFromPoint()`.

Is the only difference in *uFlags* parameter? Can I just use `ChildWindowFromPointEx()` everywhere and pass `CWP_ALL` when I need `ChildWindowFromPoint()` behavior?

Comment: According to what MSDN says...yes they're **exactly** the same (except uFlags parameter you can use to skip certain windows). About their implementation? God knows...

Comment: Who is close-voting this as "opinion based" I wonder? Have you spent not enough time trying to figure out the subtle difference between two seemingly identical API concepts?

Comment: I voted "opinion based" because it's best option I have there...If according to documentation they're identical then a discussion is pure speculation.

Comment: @Adriano: Where does the documentation explicitly say they are identical?

Comment: Description of both function is identical (all but what's driven by flags in ChildWindowFromPointEx) then I would safely assume they're unless we have any other evidence...

Comment: Pointless question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it helps at all, I hacked up a quick test application that calls both functions and stepped into the disassembled USER32.DLL to see where the calls go.

For `ChildWindowFromPoint`, after some preamble, I reached this point:

[image: child]

The main processing was delegated to the call at `75612495`.

Then, for `ChildWindowFromPointEx`, I step into the assembly and get this:

[image: childex]

As that entry point is the target of the call from the first function, it seems pretty clear to me that `ChildWindowFromPoint` calls `ChildWindowFromPointEx`, presumably with `uFlags` set to `CWP_ALL` (my assembler knowledge is limited but I'm looking hard at that `push 0` before the call - `CWP_ALL` is defined as zero).

Answer (score 1):

If you intent to always use ChildWindowFromPointEx with CWP_ALL, you could just use ChildWindowFromPoint().

If you intent to always use ChildWindowFromPoint, you could just use ChildWindowFromPointEx with CWP_ALL.

ChildWindowFromPoint is equivalent to ChildWindowFromPointEx with CWP_ALL.

Advice: use ChildWindowFromPointEx (you may one day have usage for other flags value)

Comment: The question was the other way around - if I need `ChildWindowFromPoint()` can I use `ChildWindowFromPointEx()` with `CWP_ALL`?

Comment: Sure! Yes. That is what all the guys are just telling you